# PHP PDO - How to Output Results from Three Tables

Tags: php, database, pdo

I have a car booking system database that i am in the process of building. I have 3 tables:

car_table:

```
ID     | car_make | car_name
1      | Ford     | Focus
2      | BMW      | Z3
3      | Audi     | A5
```

booking_table:

```
booking_ID  | booking_time | total_cost | etc..
125674      | 2013-02-02   | 91.55     
887463      | 2013-01-19   | 52.00     
209930      | 2013-01-11   | 23.99
```

reservation_table:

```
ID     | booking_ID | car_ID
1      | 125674     | 2
2      | 887463     | 2
3      | 209930     | 1
```

So the reservation_table links the cars with the bookings. Now i am wanting to output the following result in a table for the user:

```
booking_ID | booking_time | total_cost | car_ID | car_make | car_model
```

How can i output the results for this, so far i have this almost working:

```
$query = " 
SELECT 
    booking_ID, 
    total_cost, 
    booking_time, 
    customer_ID,
    car_ID
FROM 
    bookings_table as bb,
    reservation_table as br 
WHERE 
    bb.booking_ID = br.booking_ID AND
    payment_success=true   
ORDER BY 
    booking_ID desc 
LIMIT 
    10
";

try { 
    $stmt = DB::get()->prepare($query); 
    $stmt->execute(); 

    $rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
}  
catch(PDOException $ex) { 
    // Failed 
} 

foreach($rows as $row):
    <td>'.$row['booking_ID'].'</td>
    etc...
endforeach;
```

Which displays as below:

```
booking_ID | booking_time | total_cost | car_ID | car_make | car_model 
125674     | 2013-02-02   | 91.55      | 2      |          |
```

So i can get the car_ID from the reservation_table but i don't know how i can also pull out the car_make/model by taking the car_ID from the reservation_table.

Comment: Do you use foreign keys?

Comment: i do not use foreign keys and not too sure what they are, would this be a way of achieving it?